# Why i keep getting all the system paths when i startup the cmder?

Tags: command-line, path, cmder

I'm new to cmder so excuse me if it's a basic question.

So when I open cmder, I keep getting these PATHS as "were unexpected at this time"

An image for the paths that load on startup:

[image]

I tried to extract cmder to another folder, delete them from user/system variables and add them according to [cmder-github-wiki](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Setting-up-Environment-Variables) but I kept getting the same bug/error/hint or whatever it is.

I don't know if it affect my workflow or not but I hate seeing errors before I begin anything! xD

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvmoh.png):

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Check your PATH variable for syntax errors, especially near any occurance of Python related things.
- Check something like an "autostart.bat" that CMDer runs at every start. The culprit may be located there, near any occurance of PATH or invoking files or directories which do not exist anymore.
- Please clarify: What exactly are you invoking and in which directory, to start CMDer / to get this output? Which files did you edit and what are the contents of those files?
- As last resort try uninstalling and reinstalling CMDer. The execution is probably broken since the move to another directory you described and the problem might be hard to track.